# Решение задач о рюкзаке методом ветвей и границ

Tags: c#, алгоритм, математика

Пытаюсь реализовать решение задач о рюкзаке методом ветвей и границ. По условию вместительность рюкзака ограничена, а предметы можно положить только один раз. Нужно получить максимальную суммарную полезность. Вот код метода, который ее вычисляет:

```
void GetMaxSumAvailability(List<Item> ItemList, int i, int currentWeight, int currentCost)
{
    if(i <= ItemList.Count - 1)
    {
        // Если по весу проходит, то прибавляем стоимость и суммарный вес 
        if (currentWeight + ItemList[i].Weight <= width)      
        {
            ItemList[i].Use = true;
            GetMaxSumAvailability(ItemList, i + 1, currentWeight + ItemList[i].Weight, currentCost + ItemList[i].Availability);
        }
        // Иначе не берем и смотрим следующий элемент
        else
        {
            ItemList[i].Use = false;
            GetMaxSumAvailability(ItemList, i + 1, currentWeight, currentCost);
        }
    }
    if (maxCost < currentCost && width >= currentWeight)
    {
        ItemList.ForEach(delegate(Item item) { if (item.Use) maxCost += item.Availability; });
        GetMaxSumAvailability(ItemList, i + 1, currentWeight, currentCost);
    }
}
```

Проблема заключается в неправильном выводе. К примеру, пусть width (вместительность рюкзака) = 5. Есть три предмета:

1. Вес = 4; Ценность = 100
2. Вес = 2; Ценность = 60
3. Вес = 2; Ценность = 60

Тогда на выводе я получу 100, когда очевидно, что если взять 2 и 3 предмет, то суммарная стоимость будет 120.

Однако, следующий пример выполняется правильно:
widht = 14

1. Вес = 5; Ценность = 3
2. Вес = 10; Ценность = 5
3. Вес = 6; Ценность = 3
4. Вес = 5; Ценность = 2

В итоге я получу 7, что подтверждает следующая пикча:
[image: В квадратных скобках указаны суммарная ценность на данном шаге алгоритма, оптимальное решение помечено. Косая линия говорит о том, что предмет взят, горизонтальная говорит об обратном.]

Comment: пожалуйста, покажите фрагменты с данными

Comment: Не совсем понял, какие именно данные вы хотите увидеть

Comment: меня интересует фрагмент, где Вы её вызываете.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov `GetMaxSumAvailability(ItemList, 0, 0, 0);` вызывается по кнопке

Comment: спасибо........

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>Уберите  `GetMaxSumAvailability` в `else` - не надо подменять накопленные параметры текущими.

Оставьте только `ItemList[i++].Use = false;`</s> Увы, не всё так просто.

В подобного рода задачах есть "жадная" стратегия, когда захватываются сначала более ценные предметы. Но данная реализация - точно не такая, поскольку набивает рюкзак первым, что туда может влезть. И обе эти реализации грешат отсутствием какого бы то ни было перебора.

Если говорить о графике, то горизонтальная линия при подобном подходе отсутствует, а ограничения лишь маскируют этот факт. Чтобы эта линия возникала, надо рассматривать вариант с false даже в том случае, когда предмет влезает. Потому что в приведённом виде алгоритм не проверяет, что могло бы оказаться в рюкзаке вместо текущего предмета. И, таким образом, не рассматривает все варианты.

В конечном итоге, все стратегии перебора ведут к одним и тем же допустимым наборам. Единственная внятная оптимизация состоит в той же "жадной" стратегии, позволяющей быстрее набить рюкзак и тем самым - отсечь недопустимые варианты.
Метод ветвей и границ в данном случае ведёт только к тому, что рюкзак с вещами будет объявлен вершиной графа, а процесс набивания рюкзака - движением по его рёбрам.

Итак, рекомендаций две:
1. Упорядочить предметы по весу и начинать перебор с более тяжёлых (жадная стратегия).
2. Рассматривать вариант `ItemList.Use = false` даже и в том случае, когда предмет влазит в рюкзак. Поскольку рекурсия в конце концов приведёт к оценке, то достаточно просто сравнивать эти два варианта при их наличии (бинарный перебор).