# Динамическое программирование. Алгоритм

Tags: алгоритм

Задача такая - дано положительное число n, целые числа в порядке возрастания p<sub>1</sub> < p<sub>2</sub> < ... < p<sub>k</sub>, и c<sub>1</sub>, c<sub>2</sub>, ..., c<sub>k</sub>. p<sub>i</sub> - координаты точек на оси, c<sub>i</sub> - их веса. Нужно выбрать точки так, чтобы сумма их весов была максимальной, но расстояние между любой парой точек была не меньше n.

Я догадываюсь, что задача решается с помощью динамического программирования, но возникла сложность с алгоритмом - как, зная набор из k-1 точек с максимальным весом, найти набор для k?

Comment: Динамика вперёд: F[i] - максимальная сумма, если взять текущую точку. 
Начальное состояние - F[i] = a_i
Пересчёт - F[j] = max { F[k] + | p_k <= p_j - n } + a_j.
Ответ - максимум по всем F
Сложность если не совсем в лоб то линейная.

Comment: @pavel, что значит "| p_k <= p_j - n"?

Comment: таких что расстояние между ними больше  n.

Comment: тогда знак "+" лишний?

Answer (score 1):

Эта задача динамического программирования нелинейна.
Оптимальное решение для **k** точек в общем случае не содержит оптимального набора для **k-1** точек.

Но если говорить о множестве всех возможных наборов для данного **k**, то при отбрасывании любой его точки каждый получаемый набор с очевидностью является допустимым для **k-1**. Но это - совсем другая сложность алгоритма.

Поставленная задача - типичная "задача о рюкзаке", на сайте есть [разбор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/470464/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87-%D0%BE-%D1%80%D1%8E%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86).
Возникнут конкретные проблемы - будем разбираться.

Comment: А как тогда, хотя бы примерно, составить алгоритм этой задачи?

Comment: @Parket Добавил ссылку.

Comment: Проблемы все-таки возникли http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/497796/Динамическое-программирование-алгоритм