# Динамическое программирование, алгоритм

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Задача такая:

> Дано положительное число n, целые числа в порядке возрастания
>   p<sub>1</sub> < p<sub>2</sub> < ... < p<sub>k</sub>, и c<sub>1</sub>,
>   c<sub>2</sub>, ..., c<sub>k</sub> (0 < k < 10^5; 0 <= n, p<sub>i</sub>
>   < 10^9, 0 < c<sub>i</sub> < 10^9).  p<sub>i</sub> - координаты точек
>   на оси, c<sub>i</sub> - их веса. Нужно выбрать точки так, чтобы сумма
>   их весов была максимальной, но расстояние между любой парой точек было
>   не меньше n (n - расстояние на оси).

Я делал так - на i-м шаге для каждой точки запоминал число, равное максимальной допустимой сумме совокупности i точек с учётом их весов, расположенных по возрастанию, и оканчивающейся данной точкой.

В общем случае не работает (неверный ответ), но я не смог найти примеров с ошибкой. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

---

Тестовый пример (на обоих программа работает верно):

1. Ввод

   ```
   4 10
   5 10 15 20
   100 50 100 300
   ```

   Вывод

   ```
   400
   ```
2. Ввод

   ```
   5 15
   2 14 25 31 37
   8 19 20 11 25
   ```

   Вывод

   ```
   44
   ```

---

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> f(const std::vector<int> &first, const std::vector<int> &v1, const std::vector<int> &v2, int n1, int n2) {
    int a = -1000000000;
    std::vector<int> ans(n1);
    for (int i = 0; i != n1; ++i) {
        if (v1[i] <= n2) {
            ans[i] = a;
        } else {
            std::vector<int> A(n1);
            int j = 0;
            while (abs(v1[i] - v1[j]) > n2) {
                A[j] = first[j];
                ++j;
            }
            int m = *std::max_element(A.begin(), A.end());
            if (m == 0) {
                ans[i] = a;
            } else {
                ans[i] = m + v2[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return ans;
}

int main() {
    int n1, n2;
    std::cin >> n1 >> n2;
    std::vector<int> v1(n1);
    for (size_t i = 0; i != n1; ++i) {
        std::cin >> v1[i];
    }
    std::vector<int> v2(n1);
    for (size_t i = 0; i != n1; ++i) {
        std::cin >> v2[i];
    }
    std::vector<int> ans;
    std::vector<int> c = f(v2, v1, v2, n1, n2);
    ans.push_back(*std::max_element(c.begin(), c.end()));
    for (int i = 0; i != n1; ++i) {
        std::vector<int> x = f(c, v1, v2, n1, n2);
        ans.push_back(*std::max_element(x.begin(), x.end()))
        c = x;
    }
    std::cout << *std::max_element(ans.begin(), ans.end());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Дайте тестовый пример

Comment: Какого порядка может быть k?

Comment: Не работает код? Не работает алгоритм? Приведите testcase (а лучше два).

Comment: Поправил условие

Comment: Что за общий случай, при котором программа не работает? Это задача с hackerrank (или подобного)? Например, на hackerrank у Вас даже может быть абсолютно верный алгоритм, но он не будет проходить по времени. Т.е. не оптимизированный алгоритм может не пройти. Если задача с такого ресурса, то укажите ссылку. Также, если Вы пишите комментарий, то указывайте в начале комментария ник, к кому Вы обращаетесь (см. справку справа). Иначе, вопрошающие не узнают, что Вы отреагировали на их замечания и Ваш вопрос "потонет" в море остальных.

Comment: И еще... Или уточните условие, или вот такой testcase не прокатит ***4 10 5 10 15 20 0 50 100 300***

Comment: @MaxZS, задача с закрытого контеста. В вопросе я вроде написал, что не работает из-за неправильного ответа на каком-то тесте (WA).

Comment: Так я Вам привел пример, когда она не будет работать. Ищите ошибку и исправляйте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Учитывая, что все веса положительные, все точки удовлетворяющие вашему условию **|P[i] - P[j]| < n, i # j** и будут решением. Это очевидно.